# Velocity and translation in UIPanGestureRecognizer begin state

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm handling events with UIPanGestureRecognizer when state of sender is begin. In this state I measure velocity an translation. I always get nonzero velocity. Sign of translation is usually the same as velocty (and translation is a small nonzero number), but sometimes translaton is equal to 0. Why?

I've got it on IPhone 7 with iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the pan gesture recognizer begins recognizing a gesture when it detects a movement. The first touch on the screen is not yet a pan, it is just a touch. The finger has to move at least a tiny bit for it to be considered a pan. And if it moved a tiny bit in one direction, the velocity will also be in that direction

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer) say:

> A panning gesture is continuous. It begins (UIGestureRecognizer.State.began) when the minimum number of fingers allowed (minimumNumberOfTouches) **has moved enough to be considered a pan**.

(emphasis mine.)

The translation can be 0 if you move your finger in one direction, and then back to its original place, and the total movement was enough for the UIPanGestureRecognizer to be considered a pan.